# Finding the Mid-Band Gain of a Transistor

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

I am studying for an exam working on the current problem:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8WY4T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have already found:

$$Q-Point = (I_{DS},V_{DS}, V_{GS} = (.783mA, 1.32V, 14.21 V)$$

Givens: 
$$V_{TN} = 2V$$
$$K_n = .001 mA/V^2$$

Current question: Find:
$$A_{vin} = V_o/V_{in}$$
$$A_v = V_o/V_s$$

My work:

$$A_v = -g_mR_D(R_{in}/(R_{in}+R_i)$$
$$R_{in} = R_1||R_2 = 750k$$
$$I_{bias} = V_{DD}/(R_1+R_2) = .005mA$$
$$I_{DQ} = 5I_{bias} = .025mA$$
$$g_m = 2\sqrt{K_nI_{DQ}} = 3.16*10^{-4}$$
$$A_v = -g_mR_D(R_{in}/(R_{in} + R_i))$$
$$A_v = -1.31 V$$

Is my logic to find Av correct? How would I start to find Avin?

Comment: I am afraid, you forgot to take RL into account (RL||RD).

Comment: Another little thing: the gain must be - by Definition- dimensionless, so pay attention to the way you express it (i.e, not in volts)

Comment: ?? Vgs = 14.21V ??  (red flag )  \$1M/(1M+3M)*20V=5V=V_{gs}\$

Comment: What book do you use? So I can refer to the formulas used in your book. Also, please provide the edition you are using. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar problem as to yours which you can refer to, and solve your question.

For the circuit below, the transistor parameters are K n = 0.5 mA/V 2 , V TN = 2V, λ = 0, C gs = .1pF, and C gd = 1pF. Determine (a) the Miller capacitance, and (b) the upper 3dB frequency of the small-signal voltage gain.

[image: This is a solution from Donald A Naemen,s book names Electronic Circuits Analysis And Design]